# Java prototype clone is not working as expected?

Tags: java, design-patterns, prototype

```
public abstract class SwimmersPrototype implements Cloneable {
    public SwimmersPrototype clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        return (SwimmersPrototype)super.clone();
    }
}
```

SwimmersPrototype.java

```
public class Swimmers extends SwimmersPrototype{
    List<Swimmer> swimmers;
    SortStrategy sortStrategy;

    public Swimmers() {
        swimmers = new ArrayList();
    }

    public List<Swimmer> sort() {
        return sortStrategy.sort(swimmers);
    }

    @Override
    public SwimmersPrototype clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        SwimmersPrototype swp = (Swimmers)super.clone();
        return swp;
    }
}
```

Here i want to clone an object of this class, Swimmers.

```
public class Swim extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Swimmers swimmers;
    Swimmers swimmersCopy;
    /**
     * Creates new form Swim
     */
    public Swim() {
        initComponents();
        swimmers = new Swimmers();
        fillSwimmers();
        fillTable(swimmers.getSwimmers());
        jTableListener();

        try {
            swimmersCopy = (Swimmers)swimmers.clone();

        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Swim.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

After calling sort, that change swimmers list of the original class, the copy object, swimmersCopy is also changed.

Here I'm just displaying swimmers list of original object in a table, I can sort by a property on it, but whenever default sort button is clicked i want to list swimmers by the default order that they inserted before? But applying sort, changes the swimmers list of the cloned object too?

Comment: Start learning: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/

Comment: Side note: Don't use raw types when constructing the ArrayList. The correct syntax (for Java 7+) is `swimmers = new ArrayList<>();` Also, `sortStrategy` will be `null` and will throw an NPE when `sort()` is called, but I assume there's more to the code that you haven't shown, being unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `clone()` method of class `Object` only does shallow cloning. As the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) says, you need to implement deep cloning yourself:

> By convention, the object returned by this method should be
>   independent of this object (which is being cloned). To achieve this
>   independence, it may be necessary to modify one or more fields of the
>   object returned by super.clone before returning it. Typically, this
>   means copying any mutable objects that comprise the internal "deep
>   structure" of the object being cloned and replacing the references to
>   these objects with references to the copies.

What this means is that your original source code just performs a shallow copy:

```
public class Swimmers extends SwimmersPrototype{
    List<Swimmer> swimmers;
    SortStrategy sortStrategy;

    public Swimmers() {
        swimmers = new ArrayList();
    }

    public List<Swimmer> sort() {
        return sortStrategy.sort(swimmers);
    }

    @Override
    public SwimmersPrototype clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        SwimmersPrototype swp = (Swimmers)super.clone();
        return swp;
    }
}
```

The above implementation of the `clone()` method leaves the field `swimmers` of the original object and its clone both pointing at the same `List`. Therefore, when you change the list through one of the objects, you see the same change through the other object. To perform a deep copy, you need to do this:

```
    @Override
    public Swimmers clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        Swimmers swp = (Swimmers)super.clone();
        swp.swimmers = new ArrayList<>(swimmers);
        return swp;
    }
```

However, as you said in a comment, you prefer not to copy `swimmers` but instead implement a copy-on-write policy. First, you should be aware that it is very tricky to get copy-on-write absolutely correct in a multithreaded application, if there is a chance that your Swimmers object will be used concurrently by multiple threads. If that's not an issue in your case, you can simply make the following change to the `sort()` method:

```
    public List<Swimmer> sort() {
        swimmers = new ArrayList<>(swimmers);  // Copy on write
        return sortStrategy.sort(swimmers);
    }
```

Here, we are making a copy of the `swimmers` list to make sure we don't sort a list that is potentially shared. By making a copy, we know that this object is the only one that holds a reference to the list we are going to modify.

The above modification would unnecessarily add the overhead of a list copy even if the object has never been cloned. To avoid this overhead, you can add a reference count field which you increase in the `clone()` method (and think of some way of decreasing it when the cloned object is no longer in use). Then you only need to copy the list if the reference count is more than 1.

By the way, as a general rule, before using the Cloneable interface all Java developers should read what Josh Bloch has to say about it in his book [Effective Java](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA54).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to modify any property on the cloned object.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye well, if you don't modify any property on the cloned object, then your cloned object will *refer to the same list* as the original object.

Comment: I think it is like "COPY ON WRITE". So as to utilize memory space.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye if your sortStrategy.sort method sorts the list in-place (which it appears it does) then you should do something like `return (swimmers = sortStrategy.sort(new ArrayList<>(swimmers)));` to ensure the original list remains unmodified.

Comment: If you can, I need an explanation?

Comment: @HenokTesfaye I've expanded my answer with explanations.

Comment: Thank you @DodgyCodeExeception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187667/discussion-between-henok-tesfaye-and-dodgycodeexception).

Answer (score 1):

The default version of `clone()` method creates the shallow copy of an object. The shallow copy of an object will have exact copy of all the fields of original object. If original object has any references to other objects as fields, then only references of those objects are copied into clone object, copy of those objects are not created. That means any changes made to those objects through clone object will be reflected in original object or vice-versa. Shallow copy is not 100% disjoint from original object. Shallow copy is not 100% independent of original object.

[More info](https://javaconceptoftheday.com/difference-between-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is that the `clone()` method doesn't copy the whole object : the created copy will here share the same list.
The usage of the `clone()` method is a hazardous way of proceeding. What you may prefer is for example use a copy constructor :

```
public Swimmers(Swimmers s) {
    this.swimmers = new ArrayList<Swimmer>(s.swimmers);
}
```

Note that on this example, the copy constructor of `Swimmers` calls the copy constructor of `ArrayList`.

Comment: You should remove the word "typically"; this is simply how it works. And not use raw types in constructing the ArrayList.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thank you !